# Avoiding SQL Server 2005 tables with same names, but with different owners

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions, sql-server-2005

What is the most likely cause of this behavor with SQL Server 2005?

TEST #1:

I run Management Studio Express, connect to my local database with "windows authentication" and see that I have 1 database, and 1 table called dbo.MyTable.

Running "SELECT * FROM MyTable" (and dbo.MyTable) shows it DOES exist, but is empty.

---

TEST #2:

I re-run Management Studio Express, connect to my 1 database with "sql authentication" myLogin/myPassword and see that I have a dbo.MyTable.

Running "SELECT * FROM MyTable" (and dbo.MyTable) gives:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 2 
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'MyTable', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.
```

---

TEST #3:

Running some common vb.net code, using my SQL authentication myLogin/myPassword, shows that I can read/write to MyTable with no problem.... and the table contains 100s of good records.

Do I really have 2-3 different tables here?  (I only need 1.)  I really *NEVER* need to have "multiple tables, with the same name, but my different owners".

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The error you give states that your Management Studio Express connection using SQL Authentication is trying to query MyTable in the `master` database.  I highly doubt that that's the database that you want to be using.

In Management Studio make sure you're selecting your database.  You can use the drop-down menu in the toolbar or, assuming your database is called MyDatabase, you can execute a USE command and then your SELECT.

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Your VB.NET app's connection string probably already has this set up in it.  It'll be the `database` attribute or the `initial catalog` attribute, and the value would be MyDatabase.

Comment: Did that behavior change from SQL 2000 to 2005?  (I never remember having that problem in the past.)  Also... why does Test #1 show "table exists... but contains 0 records"?